# upload swf file and show preview before saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, flash

I am having a HTML file input in order to upload multiple files.

```
 <input type="file" id="file_uploader" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept=".png,.jpg,.swf,.gif">
```

i used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded) to show preview of the image files (jpg,png,gif) and is working like a charm.
But when trying preview a swf file I face some difficulties..
I use the [embed](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) tag to preview the swf file with no luck. No error, is showing and I also can't see the swf file. 
The code I use :

HTML

`<embed id="flash">`

Jquery

```
function local_preview() {
        $("#file_uploader").change(function() {
            readURL(this);
        })
    }

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#flash').attr('src',e.target.result);
                $('#flash').attr('type',"application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie");
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

What is the problem in the solution I try?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm having the same issue. :(

Comment: Sorry, i did not found a solution for this one. In the end I did not use swf files. I you find a solution please share.